# How to record a video in 120 fps or 240 fps using objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, avfoundation

Can any one help me regarding recording a video in 240 fps or 120 fps by default its taking 30 fps for recording session using AVCapture session.

Used this library record video
https://github.com/shu223/SlowMotionVideoRecorder

Comment: add some code up to now what you tried. Developers can resolve your problem easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you are using the library you specified, you could check the *ViewController.m* class in the *SlowMotionVideoRecorder demo class* included in the repo you specified.

Here's the code to do so using the specified library:

> [self.captureManager switchFormatWithDesiredFPS:desiredFps];

Here's the generic method using AVCaptureDevice as done in the library:

> AVCaptureDevice *videoDevice = [AVCaptureDevicedefaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
>   videoDevice.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, (int32_t)desiredFPS);
>               videoDevice.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, (int32_t)desiredFPS);

Comment: Yes but when I am trying to change the FPS the AVCaptureDevice is not configuring according to it. 
here is the console log for AVCaptureDevice object

<AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x28265dda0 'vide'/'420v' 1920x1080, { 2- 30 fps}, HRSI:3264x1836, fov:54.267, supports vis, max zoom:95.62 (upscales @1.55), AF System:1, ISO:24.0-768.0, SS:0.000024-0.500000>

Comment: Did you use the library to perform this task?